# How to save rbind to a data_table[SOLVED]

Tags: r

I'm trying to add a row to a table, and while I can get rbind to work on its own, I would like to save it to the original table. For example:

```
 df <- data.frame(DATE = c('07/01/2022', '08/01/2022'),
                     `0` = c(4, 4),
                     `1` = c(5, 3),
                      `2` = c(5,3), check.names = FALSE)
```

| Date | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07/01/2022 | 4 | 5 | 5 |
| 08/01/2022 | 4 | 3 | 3 |

```
df2 <- data.frame(V1 = 2,
                     V2 = 4,
                     V3 = 5)
```

| V1 | V2 | V3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 4 | 5 |

I'm trying to add the values of V1, V2, and V3 below the last row of the first table, but only for columns 0:3. The code I'm trying is below:

```
df[2:4] <- rbind(df[2:4], setNames(data.frame(TOTAL = 'Weights', df2), names(df[2:4])))
```

which causes the following error:

```
✖ Existing data has 3 rows.
✖ Element 1 of assigned data has 4 rows.
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
```

This is the output I would like saved:

| Date | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07/01/2022 | 4 | 5 | 5 |
| 08/01/2022 | 4 | 3 | 3 |
|  | 2 | 4 | 5 |

Comment: I think there's some more confusion here. Inferring that the `df2` columns `V1:V3` should be placed (whether or not they retain names) under `df` columns `\`0\`:\`2\``, then `df[1:3]` is selecting the columns `Date`, `\`0\``, and `\`1\``.

Comment: I apologize, that was a typo. See edits. Still can't seem to get it to work, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to use `data.table::rbindlist(list(...), fill=TRUE, use.names=TRUE)` or just `dplyr::bind_rows(...)` when row-binding tables that I want to "just combine" based on names, regardless of missing columns and order of columns.

In order to do that, we do need the names to be the same, though ...

```r
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(df, setNames(df2, names(df)[-1])),
          use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
#          DATE     0     1     2
#        <char> <num> <num> <num>
# 1: 07/01/2022     4     5     5
# 2: 08/01/2022     4     3     3
# 3:       <NA>     2     4     5

library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df, setNames(df2, names(df)[-1]))
#         DATE 0 1 2
# 1 07/01/2022 4 5 5
# 2 08/01/2022 4 3 3
# 3       <NA> 2 4 5
```

In order to be able to do this in base R alone, we need to fill out `df2` to include columns (and order) from `df`.

```r
names(df2) <- names(df)[-1]
newdf2 <- cbind(df[NA,][1,setdiff(names(df), names(df2)),drop=FALSE], df2)
rbind(df, newdf2[,names(df)])
#          DATE 0 1 2
# 1  07/01/2022 4 5 5
# 2  08/01/2022 4 3 3
# NA       <NA> 2 4 5
```

- we need `drop=FALSE` (repeatedly) because base R's `[` tends to drop to a vector when the column selection reduces to a single column, adding `drop=FALSE` keeps it as a frame
- **ensure we have all the same columns**: `df[NA,...]` is to convert all values to their respective `NA` types (there are at least six different kinds of `NA`), and it is generally best to make sure that the column types being combined are the same (otherwise errors or logical problems);
- **ensure the columns are in the same order**: the use of `newdf2` and eventually `newdf2[, names(df)]` are to make sure that all columns are in precisely the same order

Comment: Is there a way to pipe this to a table, so I can modify it further from there? That's where the error is coming up. I can generate the standalone rbind table, but trying to replace the columns is the issue.

Comment: `df %>% bind_rows(setNames(df2, names(df)[-1]))` works, what did you try?

Comment: I tried that, and it wouldn't save to the actual table.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is essentially replace the old columns with those new columns shown above.

Comment: *"wouldn't save"*... do you mean adding `df <-` to the beginning so that it is actually updated? That is `df <- df %>% bind_rows(setNames(df2, names(df)[-1]))`

Comment: As for *"replace the old columns"*, I don't understand, your question asks about adding rows.

Comment: I apologize, the phrasing there is off. I tried adding df <- at the beginning, which generated the error in the question.

Comment: The error in the OP is partly because you cannot `rbind` to _some_ columns and not others. There is no notion in R of a frame where columns have differing numbers of rows. What about the code I suggested does does not work for you?

Comment: I see, I wasn't aware that you couldn't do that. Thanks for letting me know. I get the following error for your code: ! Can't combine `..1$0` <double> and `..2$0` <character>.  Could I also default the empty values to NA to make rbind work, so that there wouldn't be differing numbers of rows?

Comment: This new error suggests your sample data is not representative of your real data. A column has one class, you cannot rbind a column where it is `character` in one and `numeric` in the other. If you don't need the numeric values to remain numbers (i.e., you are no longer calculating on them), then convert them to strings using `as.character` or `sprintf`.